# Calling a controller method whenever the value of a {{input}} Ember Handlebars helper changes

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Ember 1.0.0 RC3 provides a Handlebars helper named [`{{input}}`](http://emberjs.com/blog/2013/04/21/ember-1-0-rc3.html#toc_new-input-and-textarea-helpers). 
Instead of merely updating a String property in the underlying controller, I would like to additionally **call a method** on the underlying controller whenever the input has changed.

Is there a way to call a controller method after changes to an `{{input}}` textfield?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `.observes("propertyChangedByInputHelper")` on the controller method that shall react on changes.

```
<--Handlebars template -->
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="autocomplete">
        {{input type="text" value=searchText placeholder="Search users..."}}
        <table>
            {{#each searchResults}}
                <tr><td>
                {{#linkTo "user" this}}
                    {{firstName}} {{lastName}}
                {{/linkTo}}
                </td></tr>
            {{/each}}
        </table>
    </script>
```

.

```
//inside Ember application / app.js
App.AutocompleteController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    searchText: null,         // mutated by "autocomplete" Handlebars template
    searchResults: Ember.A(), //initialize to empty array

    searchForUsers: function() {
        this.set("searchResults", Ember.A() ); // clear possibly non-empty array
        var searchResultsBuilder = Ember.A();
        //...
        //... making modifications to searchResultsBuilder
        //...
        this.get("searchResults").addObjects(searchResultsBuilder);
    }.observes("searchText")
});
```

<sub>N.B.: When `searchText` changes, a `.property("searchText")` wouldn't be enough to trigger the `searchForUsers` method: `.property(..)` makes the method act only lazily on demand, while `.observes(..)` makes the method act eagerly.</sub>